# How to call server side method with Ajax without WebMethod?

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax

I'm working on a Razor Web Pages project (not MVC) and I need to call a server side method from the client side. I know Ajax is the way to do this, but all the examples I've seen involve WebMethods and ScriptManager, neither of which exist in my project as it's not WebForms. Is there any other way I can do this?

Comment: Have you looked into Web API or a normal MVC controller action that returns json?

Comment: What is Razor Web Pages project? I don't have this project type in my VS2013, and googling wasn't helpful either. How is this different than MVC or WebForms?

Comment: Basically, it's different than MVC or WebForms because it's not a framework. Razor is just a view engine with a simple syntax - a way to make simple websites with server side code without a formal codebehind file or controller. When I started using it, my site was much simpler than it is now, but I don't have the time at the moment to completely redo it within one of those frameworks. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/428509ah(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score -1, accepted):

New way of doing is to use SignalR.Net Although component is not designed for this but it will give you heads up with websockets. So you can call server methods from javascript( Jquery)

[about singnalR](http://www.asp.net/signalr)

Comment: -1: This does not answer OP's question. Also, SignalR is intended for keep alive connections / frequent ajax updates, and is not meant to replace every single ajax call.

Comment: I agree andre but it is not wrong answer as I have already told that it is not designed for this but you could use this for calling server method.